# undefined value returning while executing sql query in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express

I am fetching values from my database having tables:
[image: tables]

My code:

```
function listshops(callback)
{   
 client.connection.query('select * from shop',function(err,rows){
   if(rows.length>0)
   {  
     for(var i=0;i<rows.length;i++)
     {   
       var shopIdFetched = rows[i].shopId;
        client.connection.query('select * from image where shopId=?',shopIdFetched,function(err,data){
           if(data.length > 0){
            console.log(rows[i],data);
            }

        });

     }

   }

 });
}
```

But when displaying result, the first query shows a undefined value.
[image]

When i gives rows [0] and rows[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqTUF.png) the values are fetching. But i need to implement rows[i].

Comment: Just by looking at it, seems to be a asynch problem, can you do a console.log, and check what the i value is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misunderstand how asynchronous calls are make.

What happens when you run this part of code?

```
     for(var i=0;i<rows.length;i++)
     {   
       var shopIdFetched = rows[i].shopId;
       client.connection.query(...) //these are asynchronous methods    
     }
```

For `rows.length=10`, it will call 10 times the client.connection.query, which is unfortunately asynchronous method, therefore it is not executed yet, but it put 10 asynchronous methods to Event Stack.

After this method synchronously finishes and one of method indicates, the call to database is finished, the method is executed, which is this

```
        if(data.length > 0){
             console.log(rows[i],data);
        }
```

However at this point, the for-cycle already finished, the `i=10`, therefore rows[10] is undefined (because for `rows.length=10` you have data in `rows[0]` to `rows[9]`

---

One workaround can be to put another method to the inner scope, something like this

```
for(var i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    x(i);
}

function x(i){
    console.log(i);
    //this i will be same even after asynchronous paradighm
}
```

---

The same thing can be written as this

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    (function(i){
        console.log(i);
    })(i)
}
```

In your case

```
 for(var i=0;i<rows.length;i++)
 {   
   (function(i){
   var shopIdFetched = rows[i].shopId;
    client.connection.query('select * from image where shopId=?',shopIdFetched,function(err,data){
       if(data.length > 0){
        console.log(rows[i],data);
        }

    });
    })(i);
 }
```

---

For better understanding, this would do the same

```
 for(var index=0;index<rows.length;index++)
 {   
   (function(i){
   var shopIdFetched = rows[i].shopId;
    client.connection.query('select * from image where shopId=?',shopIdFetched,function(err,data){
       if(data.length > 0){
        console.log(rows[i],data);
        }

    });
    })(index);
 }
```

In previous example, we just shadowed variable `i` with different variable `i` (if more variables with same name are created, the one which is in the most inner scope will be selected)

Comment: i understood whats the problem. My question is how to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

You can not rely on `i` in async callbacks, because it was changed at time handler called.

You should to create some scope to save iteration data (i or row).

With `Array.prototype.forEach`:

```
rows.forEach(row => {
  var shopIdFetched = row.shopId;
  client.connection.query('select * from image where shopId=?',shopIdFetched,function(err,data){
    if(data.length > 0){
      console.log(row,data);
    }
  });
});
```

With `IIFE`:

```
for (var i=0; i<rows.length; i++) {
  !function(i) {
    // here you can use `i`/`rows[i]` without initial issue
  }(i);
}
```